# Calling a method within a controller that's within a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Been trying to figure this out for too long now. Maybe someone can shed some light:

Am experimenting with custom directives and as an exercise I'm trying to create a method within the custom directive's controller that can be called from a simple button within the view. But the method isn't being called, even though I can see the method (using console) as a property within isolated scope object. Any ideas please?

HTML:

```
<my-dir>
    <p>My dir content</p>
    <p><button ng-click="hideMe()">Hide element with isolated scope</button></p>
</my-dir>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('myDir', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.hideMe = function(){

                console.log('hideMe called');

            };

        }]
    };
})
```

Comment: isolated scope only works on `template` or `templateUrl` of a directive...not when it's already in the dom

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for the insight. I've read the docs and must have missed that critical fact. I just assumed that once isolated scope was applied then the new scope would apply to the directive element itself and any pre-existing children already present in the DOM, which I assume would essentially be equal to in-lining a 'ng-controller' directive anyway. Will scan the Angular docs again now to clarify as I don't understand Angular's reasoning behind it - seems like an oversight, but there's probably a valid reason :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare your template inside the directive using `template:` property or inside an external `.html` file using `templateUrl:"path/to/template.html"`

Example using `template :`

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        template : '<p>My dir content</p><p><button ng-click="hideMe()">Hide me</button></p>',
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.hideMe = function(){
                console.log('hideMe called');
            };
        }]
    };
})
```

Example using `templateUrl :`

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl : 'my-dir.tpls.html',
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.hideMe = function(){
                console.log('hideMe called');
            };
        }]
    };
})
```

Template : my-dir.tpls.html

```
<p>My dir content</p>
<p><button ng-click="hideMe()">Hide me</button></p>
```

**HTML:**

```
<my-dir></my-dir>
```

Comment: Super, thanks for the example. As a side question, if there were multiple <my-dir>'s (used as a list for example), then would each <my-dir> have it's own isolated scope & nested controller based on the example above?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

**Directive:**

```
 app.directive('myDir', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
          $scope.hideMe = function() {
            alert('hideMe called');
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <my-dir>
    <p>My dir content</p>
    <p>
      <button ng-click="hideMe()">Hide element with isolated scope</button>
    </p>
  </my-dir>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/T96Zu/354/)**

Comment: Thank you Sajeetharan but I'm trying to avoid using the ng-controller directive within the view, and instead writing custom directives that define their own controllers (with methods).

For some reason, when the custom directive & corresponding controller is compiled the hideMe() function isn't available on the isolated scope.

Comment: @Iamme as charlietfl explained you cannot do that

Comment: The DEMO uses AngularJS 1.0.3. Later versions will not work that way.